# auto resize issue on subview appdelegate in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, autoresize

in my app i will create some `UIView` in main window and `UIView` use auto resize but this is no support

if device mode is portrait then complatly work
but devicemode is landscape login view get x position in minus.

add view on window

```
 _window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    if (!_window) _window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    [[[_window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.view_login];
```

image:
[image: my image issue on only landscape mode]

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if (!_window) _window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.window.rootViewController.interfaceOrientation;
// Set appropriate view frame (it won't be autosized by addSubview:)
CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
{
    // Need to flip the X-Y coordinates for landscape
    self.view_login.frame = CGRectMake(appFrame.origin.y, appFrame.origin.x, appFrame.size.height, appFrame.size.width+40);
}
else
{
    self.view_login.frame = appFrame;
}


[[[_window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.view_login];
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code you haven't set the autoresizing mask.
try this:

```
[self.view_login setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Comment: view_login always get portrait position

Comment: check the subviews in self.view_login

Comment: self.view_login in subview set center